# How to mock an exception for a nested function?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have this method and I would like to ensure correct behaviour when an exception is thrown. Here's the said method:

```
class MyClass {
   public int methodOne() {
      int number = getNumber();
      try {
        return modifyInt(number);
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        log.info("failed, returning original int");
        return number;
      }
   }

   public int getNumber() {...}

   public int modifyInt(int number) throws Throwable {
      ...
   }
}
```

In order to test `methodOne()` during an exception, I want to mock `modifyInt()` into throwing an exception and then the catch block would be executed. Here's my test case:

```
@Test
public void testOne() {
   MyClass mockMyClass = Mockito.spy(new MyClass());
   Mockito.doThrow(RuntimeException.class).when(mockMyClass).modifyInt(any(int.class)); // problem

   int actualNumber = mockMyClass.methodOne();
   assertEquals(expectedNumber, actualNumber);   // fails, number has been modified
}
```

I believe that my `doThrow()` is incorrect; I do not see an exception being raised and the number returned has been modified. My suspicion is that the `.when(mockMyClass)` specification only works when I literally call `mockMyClass.modifyInt()` and it does not work when it is being called as a sub-function.

How can I ensure that the `modifyInt()` function here will throw an exception through mocking?

edit: typo

Comment: `.when(mockMyClass).modifyObj` you meant `modifyInt`?

Comment: I have a hunch that it might be struggling with that any() parameter you have. Maybe try org.mockito.Matchers.anyInt().

Comment: Nope, that didn't change anything

Comment: Have just tested this code with Mockito 3.5.13 and it works as expected. Are you sure the sample reflects the actual code you run? Also, which package `any()` comes from?

Comment: I was on 2.2 and I updated to 3.3 and it's working as expected, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to mock part of the class you're being tested? it is weird, at least from my point of view.

Anyway, I think the problem is you're defining your mock like if it was a void method, and `modifyInt` is returning an int.

Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-exceptions) tutorial, but you should define the behavior in the reverse way, just like this:

```
when(mockMyClass.modifyInt(anyInt()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException())
```